# How to be notified when a VisualElement gets actually visible?

Tags: xamarin.forms

Especially i’m working with a ScrollView.

I’d like to be notified when scrolling passed certain elements

Answer (score 0):

You could get the scrolled by handling the **Scrolled** event of the ScrollView

```
<ScrollView  Scrolled="ScrollView_Scrolled" >

</ScrollView>
```

```
    private double Position = 0;
    private void ScrollView_Scrolled(object sender, ScrolledEventArgs e)
    {
        var scrollView = sender as ScrollView;

        if (Position < e.ScrollY)
        {
            //scrolled down
            Position = e.ScrollY;

            //do something you want 
        }
        else
        {
            //scrolled up

            if (Convert.ToInt16(e.ScrollY) == 0)
                Position = 0;

            //do something you want 

        }
    }
```

> notifie when scrolling passed certain elements

I don't think we could implement it even in specific platforms . But as a workaround , we could use AbsoluteLayout and lisnten the **e.ScrollY** to judge if the ScrollView scroll to some specific elements .

Comment: this can solve my problem if it is possible to reliably retrieve the y position of an element inside a scrollview (relative to the scrollview). Is it?